# Performance issues in single guard for hidden services

Tags: onion-services, guard-node, performance

From what I can read in this recent post in the [Tor blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/nine-questions-about-hidden-services), Hidden Services use one single guard, just as regular clients do. How does this affect the performance of hidden services? I know that since the single-guard proposal was implemented, the conditions on bandwidth that a node has to satisfy for becoming a guard are much stricter than before. However, for hidden services such as Facebook's, it seems that despite the load-balancing at the web server, the guard could become the bottleneck. Is there any analysis done on this?

Comment: You will find this interesting: https://github.com/DonnchaC/onionbalance/blob/develop/docs/design.rst